# How to create a diagonal multi-dimensional (ie greater than 2) in numpy

Tags: numpy

Is there a higher (than two) dimensional equivalent of diag?

```
L = [...] # some arbitrary list.
A = ndarray.diag(L)
```

will create a diagonal 2-d matrix shape=(len(L), len(L)) with elements of L on the diagonal.

I'd like to do the equivalent of:

```
length = len(L)
A = np.zeros((length, length, length))
for i in range(length):
    A[i][i][i] = L[i]
```

Is there a slick way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`diag_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices.html) to get the indices to be set.  For example,

```
x = np.zeros((3,3,3))
L = np.arange(6,9)

x[np.diag_indices(3,ndim=3)] = L
```

gives

```
array([[[ 6.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  7.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  8.]]])
```

Under the hood `diag_indices` is just the code Jaime posted, so which to use depends on whether you want it spelled out in a numpy function, or DIY.

Comment: If it fits the use case, then using the built-in function is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fancy indexing:

```
In [2]: a = np.zeros((3,3,3))

In [3]: idx = np.arange(3)

In [4]: a[[idx]*3] = 1

In [5]: a
Out[5]:
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]])
```

For a more general approach, you could set the diagonal of an arbitrarily sized array doing something like:

```
def set_diag(arr, values):
    idx = np.arange(np.min(arr.shape))
    arr[[idx]*arr.ndim] = values
```

Comment: Nice.  It looks like `np.diag_indices` is just a helper function for exactly the same.

Comment: Hmmm... I was convinced I was expanding to more dimensions something I had seen in [`/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py), but there doesn't seem to be anything quite like it there. So I guess I must have picked it from `diag_indices` but forgot it worked for an arbitrary number of dimensions.